# How to parse "dateTime.tz" in Java

Tags: java, parsing, date

The date in "dateTime.tz" format looks like this:

```
2010-07-21T314:20:5.390Z
```

How can I parse such date? I can use Regex, but probably there is a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [dateTime.tz](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MicrosyntaxDescriptions#datetime-tz) is ISO-8601 format. So, you should be able to do something like this:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

See here for example: http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/2004-09-dates

Comment: Thanks to everybody, it was a hard time to decide what answer to accept, since all of them was very close to solution :-) I ended up with SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S'Z'"); that is most close to @limc answer.

Answer (score 2):

Joda DateTime http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html has methods to deal with parsing dates

See http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser%28%29

For example:

```
public static DateTimeFormatter dateTimeParser()

    Returns a generic ISO datetime parser which parses either a date or a time or both. 
It accepts formats described by the following syntax:

     datetime          = time | date-opt-time
     time              = 'T' time-element [offset]
     date-opt-time     = date-element ['T' [time-element] [offset]]
     date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
     std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
     ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
     week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
     time-element      = HH [minute-element] | [fraction]
     minute-element    = ':' mm [second-element] | [fraction]
     second-element    = ':' ss [fraction]
     fraction          = ('.' | ',') digit+
     offset            = 'Z' | (('+' | '-') HH [':' mm [':' ss [('.' | ',') SSS]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDateFormat.parse()` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ISO standard date and time; You can parse it easily by using java.text.SimpleDateFormat - but that's not thread safe so you have to ensure that you're properly synchronizing it. Or you can use the JodaTime library, which has better thread safety.

The pattern for SimpleDateFormat which works with what you gave is "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH24:mm:ss.SSS'Z'".

Answer (score 1):

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z");
I haven't tried it.